# Truffle: calling a contract function with another contract as parameter

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am testing a token vesting contract with truffle(from openzeppelin). To release tokens you call TokenVesting.release(ERC20Basic token).

```
const tokenAddress = await ico.token.call();
var token = ERC20Basic.at(tokenAddress);

const vestingAddress = await ico.vestingAddress.call();
var vestingContract = TokenVesting.at(vestingAddress);

await vestingContract.release(token);
```

This gives me the error "Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function". Any ideas?

Edit: full release signature

```
/**
 * @notice Transfers vested tokens to beneficiary.
 * @param token ERC20 token which is being vested
 */
function release(ERC20Basic token) public {
  uint256 unreleased = releasableAmount(token);

    require(unreleased > 0);

    released[token] = released[token].add(unreleased);

    token.safeTransfer(beneficiary, unreleased);

    emit Released(unreleased);
 }
```

Comment: I already included the tokenvesting.release function, which signatures from these functions would I need to add?

Comment: Yes, when commented out it does not yield an error. I updated the post to include full signature and even body!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the contract's address as the parameter, so just do this:

```
const tokenAddress = await ico.token.call();

const vestingAddress = await ico.vestingAddress.call();
var vestingContract = TokenVesting.at(vestingAddress);

await vestingContract.release(tokenAddress);
```